# Pass selected DropDown value to the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a DropDownList and a button on my View. On click of a button, I want to pass the selected DropDown value to the controller. How to do this?

View code is as below:

```
@model Sample2.Models.LeaveType
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Status of Application";
}

@{
    List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
         {
             Text = "All",
             Value = "A",
             Selected = true
         });
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
         {
             Text = "Recommended",
             Value = "R"
         });
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
         {
             Text = "Sanctioned",
             Value = "S"
         });
}

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LeaveType1, listItems, "-- Select Status --")
        </td>
        <td>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
            {
                <input type="submit" value="Show" />
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Controller code is like this:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string Id)
    {
        using (var context = new Admin_TestEntities())
        {
            var data = context.Leave_GetDetails(Id).ToList();
            return View(data.AsEnumerable().ToList());
        }

    }
```

** Edited **

After suggestions, I changed the code as below and it is working:

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.DropDownList("Id", listItems)
            <input type="submit" value="Show" />
        }
```

Comment: You need a POST method with either `public ActionResult Index(LeaveType model)` or `public ActionResult Index(string LeaveType1)` then put your dropdown **inside** the form tags (currently you don't post back anything)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have changed to Post. Please illustrate how to put DropDownList inside Form and pass the selected DropDown value.

Comment: Just move `@Html.DropDownListFor(..)` to after the `@using (Html.BeginForm(.. ` line. But you current GET method will not work anyway - its returns a collection to the view, but the view is declared as a single `LeaveType` object (not a collection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it like that:

```
[Post]
public ActionResult Index(string fromList)
{
    ...
}
```

the view can look something like this:

```
<div>
@Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post)
{
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LeaveType1, listItems, "-- Select Status --")
     <input type="submit" />
}
</div>
```